# Bootstrap 4 Toggler Dropdown has no background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to get the toggle dropdown for smaller screens to have the same background as the regular navbar but I can not for the life of me figure out how to target it. Am I missing a bootstrap class or is something in my code causing an error? I had originally thought that the border was causing an error as I noticed the issue soon after I put it in, but removing it does nothing.

HTML...

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md" id="lp-navbar">
      <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
               <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#order-online">Order</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul> 
         </div>                    
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav><!--nav-->
```

CSS...

```
/* Navbar */
.navbar {
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
background-color: transparent;
height: 75px;
}

.navbar.scroll-navbar {
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #b94335;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}


.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link  {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 50px;
}

.navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, 
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active, 
.navbar-nav .nav-link.open,
.navbar-nav .open>.nav-link,
.navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, 
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #b94335;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-toggler-right {
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 5px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    content: "\f0c9";
    font-family: "fontawesome";
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 105px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still do not understand what you want to achieve? 
This is your living example https://www.codeply.com/go/FOTrRS7wGv

Comment: The toggler for smaller screens drops down with a transparent background. It makes the links hard to impossible to see in a lot of areas when on a webpage. (I did change the colors on the links to make them see able)

Comment: Something like this https://www.codeply.com/go/Gx9Qcvx8I6 ?

Comment: Yes! Though I need the drop down specifically to be black.

Comment: Which one do you need? You can make any `background` for `.navbar`

Comment: The navbar is supposed to be transparent. The Dropdown needs to have a black background behind the links so that they can be seen. Turning the navbar black technically works but then the navbar isn't transparent anymore

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/T3GxfVZwOj

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean! So I had to target navbarNav. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .navbar {
        height: auto;
    }
    #navbarNav{
        background: black;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/T3GxfVZwOj